# upgrade from 18 to 20 fails due to ppa's -- but ppa's don't purge

Tags: upgrade, ppa

I get the warning during

> sudo do-release-upgrade

> Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
> Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
> package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
> try the upgrade again.

Finding added repositories:

> history | grep add-apt-repository
>
> 989  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo bionic main" -u

I try to remove this:

> sudo ppa-purge -s realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com ppa:Debian/apt-repo bionic main

I get the same error again when I try to upgrade.

I notice that when I use the gui to remove ppa's they seem to re-appear.

I have also run this to gather further information

> ack "ERROR Dist-upgrade failed" /var/log/dist-upgrade/
>
> /var/log/dist-upgrade/20201013-0933/main.log 119:2020-10-13
> 09:25:13,711 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error,
> pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by
> held packages.'

Has anyone encountered this before?  Solutions appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  *yy* releases cannot use PPAs, they are used only by *yy.mm* releases as they don't contain containerized snaps.

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (whitehaven-mlk X67)
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Adjust your question to match your release, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is a different system to Ubuntu Core 18 or a Ubuntu *yy* releases.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you try to run the ppa-purge commands?

Comment: Apparently, delving into the issue via the logs, there were held packages.  Following a procedure to eliminate those seemed to allow the installation.  I don't really understand how all of these things interacted, but I got there. SO I cannot answer my own question here.  Purrg did not produce an error. It just had no discernible effect.